# Amazon EC2 Penetration Request Form

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, penetration-testing

I am writing Penetration Request Form to Amazon web services. I want help in filling the Request form, I am having dynamic IP, what shall I mention in Destination IP and source IP?
The server deployed in the AWS EC2 and running Ubuntu 12.02 OS.
The db is on another instance using the AWS RDS. No load balance - just a single server instance for the app and the single instance for the db.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Source**: The IP(s) of the machines which will initiate the scan (usually machines external to AWS - like third party pentest service)

**Destination**: Your server IPs. It is better to assign elastic IPs and then use them to fill the request. You can use the dynamic IPs, but if your instances are stopped and started before your scan test starts, then your scan may fail since your servers will have a new IP.

Comment: can i use port forwarding mechanism on my computer to make it static?